# Need to click second of elements with the same selector using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Goal:  I have several checkboxes and I need to select the second one using Puppeteer

Problem: I tried getting the ElementHandles via the page.$$ and page.click the second element [1] of the returned array, but that's failing.  I'm not are why.  The elements/checkboxes have a HTML data page of data-test="bar".

```
let foo = await page.$$('[data-test="bar"]');
await page.click(foo[1]);
```

Why isn't this working?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-liner:
`await (await page.$$('[data-test="bar"]'))[1].click();`

This is the only way to click some controls created by React, when first element is a shadow DOM element and is unclickable (page.click throws Puppeteer "Error: No element found for selector ...").
This does not work in this case: `await page.click('[data-test="bar"]:nth-child(1)')`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of performing

```
await page.click(foo[1]);
```

you could try

```
await foo[1].click();
```

If you want you use [page.click](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.1.0&show=api-pageclickselector-options) instead - you should use a **selector**, not an **element**.

Comment: OMG, I just tried this (right before you answered), and it worked.  Thanks for your response though.  So, how can I convert this into a page.click knowing I want the second elementHandle returned?

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan I believe it will be something like `await page.click('[data-test="bar"]:nth-child(1)')`